# I'm having trouble in persisting session through RemoteAuth in heroku

Tags: node.js, web, heroku, puppeteer, whatsapp

I'm having trouble persisting my WhatsApp session through RemoteAuth in Heroku. The code works fine on my local machine running Windows 10, but it's not working on Heroku.

Here's the relevant code:

```
// Importing necessary modules
const { Client, RemoteAuth } = require("whatsapp-web.js");
const { MongoStore } = require('wwebjs-mongo');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

async function addUser(userId) {
  // Creating a new client instance with RemoteAuth
  const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new RemoteAuth({
      store: new MongoStore({ mongoose: mongoose }),
      clientId: userId,
      dataPath: './Whatsapp_auth',
      backupSyncIntervalMs: 61000,
    }),
    qrMaxRetries: 5,
    puppeteer: {
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--disable-databases',
        '--disable-extensions',
        '--disable-client-side-phishing-detection',
        '--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages',
        '--disable-default-apps',
        '--hide-scrollbars',
        '--no-default-browser-check',
        '--no-first-run',
        '--disable-features=Translate,MediaRouter',
        '--single-process',
        '--window-size=10,10'
      ],
      headless: true,
    }
  });

  // Some code here ...

  client.on('remote_session_saved', async() => {
    client.destroy();
  });

  // More code here ...

  await client.initialize();
}
```

I'm trying to save the session in a MongoDB store so that I don't have to generate a new QR code every time I reinitialize the client with the same clientId. This works perfectly fine on my local machine, but on Heroku, I can't see any folder created after running this code. Additionally, after the remote_session_saved event, some data is inserted in the database, but the next time I initialize the client with the same clientId, it triggers theloading_screen event with percent 0 and then triggers the qr event.

I'm using a basic dyno on Heroku, and my buildpacks are:
heroku/nodejs
jontewks/puppeteer

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you initialize Mongoose before using it?